# Python, unit test - Pass command line arguments to setUp of unittest.TestCase

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a script that acts as a wrapper for some unit tests written using the Python `unittest` module. In addition to cleaning up some files, creating an output stream and generating some code, it loads test cases into a suite using

```
unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase()
```

I am already using `optparse` to pull out several command-line arguments used for determining the output location, whether to regenerate code and whether to do some clean up.  I also want to pass a configuration variable, namely an endpoint URI, for use within the test cases.

I realize I can add an `OptionParser` to the setUp method of the TestCase, but I want to instead pass the option to `setUp`.  Is this possible using `loadTestsFromTestCase()`?  I can iterate over the returned `TestSuite`'s `TestCases`, but can I manually call setUp on the `TestCases`?

** EDIT **
I wanted to point out that I am able to pass the arguments to `setUp` if I iterate over the tests and call `setUp` manually like:

```
(options, args) = op.parse_args()
suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(MyTests.TestSOAPFunctions)
for test in suite:
    test.setUp(options.soap_uri)
```

However, I am using `xmlrunner` for this and its run method takes a `TestSuite` as an argument.  I assume it will run the setUp method itself, so I would need the parameters available within the `XMLTestRunner`.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Well, I want to do the same thing and was going to ask this question myself. I wanted to improve over the following code because it has duplication. It does let me send in arguments to test TestCase however:

```
import unittest
import helpspot

class TestHelpSpot(unittest.TestCase):
    "A few simple tests for HelpSpot"

    def __init__(self, testname, path, user, pword):
        super(TestHelpSpot, self).__init__(testname)
        self.hs = helpspot.HelpSpot(path, user, pword)

    def test_version(self):
        a = self.hs.version()
        b = self.hs.private_version()
        self.assertEqual(a, b)

    def test_get_with_param(self):
        a = self.hs.filter_get(xFilter=1)

    def test_unknown_method(self):
        self.assertRaises(helpspot.HelpSpotError, self.hs.private_wuggienorple)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    user = sys.argv[1]
    pword = sys.argv[2]
    path = sys.argv[3]

    test_loader = unittest.TestLoader()
    test_names = test_loader.getTestCaseNames(TestHelpSpot)

    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    for test_name in test_names:
        suite.addTest(TestHelpSpot(test_name, path, user, pword))

    result = unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
    sys.exit(not result.wasSuccessful())
```

Comment: What is helpspot here?

Comment: HelpSpot is a customer service application from UserScape. I wrote a Python interface for its API - https://github.com/JohnSpeno/python-helpspot

Comment: For this to work similar to `unittest.main()` you should add `sys.exit(not result.wasSuccessful())` to the end.

Answer (score 8):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from optparse import OptionParser
    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-z", "--zebra",
                      action="store_true", dest="zebra", default=False,
                      help="run like a zebra")    


    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

    if options.zebra:
        zebrafy()


    # remove our args because we don't want to send them to unittest
    for x in sum([h._long_opts+h._short_opts for h in parser.option_list],[]):
        if x in sys.argv:
            sys.argv.remove(x)


    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Very nice. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: II wanted to add `-i` option, and used the code above... I start my test via `..\..\python\python -m unittest -v "test_activation.test_activation" -i "input_file"`. Why does this give me an error `test_activation.py: error: no such option: -m`?

Comment: This didn't work for me. However the following line to remove args worked.


del sys.argv[1:]

Answer (score 4):

I would definitely advise against passing arguments to setUp like this; setUp is intended to be called implicitly when running a test, so you shouldn't be explicitly calling it like this.

One way you could tackle this would be to set the values you need to set either as environment variables or values in a globally accessible "context" module, which would allow test cases to access them as needed. I would go for using environment variables, as it is more flexible in terms of running the tests (you're then no longer relying on command line arguments).

Comment: And then some other code relies on an environmental variable with the same name, great.

Answer (score 0):

If you define the attributes in the init method, then you can simply pass them all in the constructor like this..

```
import unittest
import helpspot

class TestHelpSpot(unittest.TestCase):
    "A few simple tests for HelpSpot"

    def __init__(self, testname, path, user, pword):
        super(TestHelpSpot, self).__init__(testname)
        self.path = path
        self.user = user
        self.pword = pword
....
....
....


if __name__ == '__main__':
    True

    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTest(TestHelpSpot("test_version", path, user, pword))    

    unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
```