# GAE Python Testing

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

First I'm quite new to GAE/Python, please bear with me. Here's the situation

Have a test_all.py which tests all the test suites in my package. The TestCase's setUp current look like;

```
import test_settings as policy # has consistency variables <- does not work

...

def setUp(self):
    # First, create an instance of the Testbed class.
    self.testbed = testbed.Testbed()
    # Then activate the testbed, which prepares the service stubs for use.
    self.testbed.activate()
    # Consistency policy nomal operations
    self.policy = None
    if policy.policy_flag == 'STRICT':
        # Create a consistency policy that will simulate the High Replication consistency model.
        self.policy = datastore_stub_util.PseudoRandomHRConsistencyPolicy(probability=0)
    # Initialize the datastore stub with this policy.
    self.testbed.init_datastore_v3_stub(consistency_policy=self.policy)
```

This is my primitive attempt to setup the datastore with different consistency policies to run tests against them. Total fail.

What I want is to run my test cases against different datastore consistencies at one go  from my root test_all.py Using the above or other, how can I do this? How do I pass in parameters to the TestCase from the test runner?

Comment: Re "total fail" -- can you show the error, or what you got vs what you expected?

Comment: policy_flat is just a variable in a different module. I *believe* changes I make to it don't propagate into the "import" in the test cases. So tests run in the default starting consistency only. Is it possible to send a parameter to the TestCase class from the runner?

Answer (score 0):

[Python, unit test - Pass command line arguments to setUp of unittest.TestCase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842168/python-unit-test-pass-command-line-arguments-to-setup-of-unittest-testcase)

The above thread shows exactly how to best pass runtime arguments to the test case. Specifically answer 2.