# Unittesting a file by calling it from another file in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I am new to unnitest module. I have a file that has unittest in it. The file is something like ...

## File1.py

```
class ABC (unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # Do some work here

    def test_123(self, a,b,c):
        # Do some work here

if __name__ == "__main__":
unittest.main()
```

***Now I am calling this file from another file by passing values to the function "test_123".*** But python displays the following error. Could anybody please help!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "caller_file.py", line 20, in <module>
r = file1.ABC()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 191, in __init__
(self.__class__, methodName))
ValueError: no such test method in <class 'file1.ABC'>: runTest
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run `file1.ABC` test case like this:

```
import unittest
import file1

suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(file1.ABC)
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

Also you need to add the `self` argument to the `setUp` and `test_123` methods and `self` should be the sole argument.

Comment: Have you removed the line `r = file1.ABC()` from the `File2.py`?

Comment: Ok this works [Test Case]. But now I can't seem to pass value to the function "test_123" from file2.py . Help Again.

Comment: You can't pass arguments to `test_*` methods directly. Take a look at this answer for a workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2081750/1240162

Comment: Actually I am reading a .txt file in File2.py and parsing it to send values to File1.py. So command line arguments won't be helpful I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I run into similar problems with my unittests because missing entries in search path for modules.

I solved it by creating

```
my_env = os.environ.copy()
        if not 'PYTHONPATH' in my_env:
            my_env['PYTHONPATH'] = ''

        my_env['PYTHONPATH'] += ';' + ';'.join(
                                    [os.path.abspath('.'),
                                    os.path.abspath('..'),
                                    os.path.abspath('..\\..')])
```

and then the call of the file

```
_ = subprocess.check_output(filepath, shell=True, env=my_env)
```

I just added the current path environment because the calling-file is in the same directories. Maybe you have to adjust that.