# How can I run automated tests with parameterised url from command line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, jenkins, python-unittest

I am creating automated tests with Python's unittest, Selenium and PhantomJS. I will have them running by Jenkins. So the list of urls could be added to Jenkins.

I found that pytest can have tests getting urls from command line, as shown on https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-automate-testing-using-selenium-webdriver-jenkins-and-allure.

However, I am using unittest framework. The main reason of doing that is that I would be testing on menus, headers and footers on 500 web pages.

So, how can I get the urls from command line and then to put them in `self.driver.get('urls_from_command_line')`?

Answer (score 0):

It depends of your configuration and code you already done for sure.
But for example some ideas how to do it:

- Store your URLs to some place (text file?) and parse the file from your unittest.
- Use Jenkins Parameterized job to invoke your python script with URL as parameter.

You can read about Python command line parameters at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/command-line-arguments-in-python)
And Jenkins Parameterized build at [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build)

Answer (score 0):

I use pytest and I have my conftest.py file and a config.py setup so that we can easily set URLs for each test as needed.

However, it looks like your question was answered within [How to use a command line argument in unittest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37194538/how-to-use-a-command-line-argument-in-unittest)

Basically, you set a base URL and include an argument to include a provided URL.