# How to pass an url as argument through commandline to run selenium python test cases

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, python-unittest

Is there any proper way to using getting url in cmd as argument along testcases.py file?

I am running below commmand in cmd to run test cases of python file:
   testcases.py "any url"

testcases.py have coding:

```
class JSAlertCheck(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("E:\chromedriver.exe")
        self.url = sys.argv[1]

    def test_Case1(self):
        driver = self.driver

    def tearDown(self):
           self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842168/python-unit-test-pass-command-line-arguments-to-setup-of-unittest-testcase

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python, unit test - Pass command line arguments to setUp of unittest.TestCase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842168/python-unit-test-pass-command-line-arguments-to-setup-of-unittest-testcase)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the discussion [Python unittest passing arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11380413/python-unittest-passing-arguments) the *Python Pundits* seems to convey that:

> Unit tests should be stand-alone which will have no dependencies outside of their `setUp()` and `tearDown()` methods. This is to make sure that each tests has minimal side-effects and reactions to the other test. Passing in a parameter defeats this property of **unittest** and thus makes them sort of invalid. Using a *Test Configuration* would have been the easiest way and more appropiate as a **unittest** should never rely on foreign data to perform the test.

If you still want to do so, here is one of the working solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  import unittest
  import sys


  class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):

      URL = "foo"

      def setUp(self):
          self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
          driver = self.driver
          driver.get(self.URL)

      def test_Case1(self):
          driver = self.driver
          print(driver.title)

      def tearDown(self):
          self.driver.quit()

  if __name__ == "__main__":
      if len(sys.argv) > 1:
          MyTest.URL = sys.argv.pop()
      unittest.main()
  ```
- CLI Command:

  ```
  python unittest_cmdline_urlASarguments.py http://www.python.org
  ```
- Output:

  ```
  C:\Users\AtechM_03\LearnAutmation\PythonProject\readthedocs>python unittest_cmdline_urlASarguments.py http://www.python.org
  [4448:5632:0606/205445.017:ERROR:install_util.cc(589)] Unable to create registry key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome for reading result=2

  DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:5634/devtools/browser/40cc6c16-1e52-4f49-a54f-08fac3ff7abc
  Welcome to Python.org
  .
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Ran 1 test in 9.534s

  OK

  C:\Users\AtechM_03\LearnAutmation\PythonProject\readthedocs>
  ```
- Commandline Snapshot:

[image: unittest_cli_url]

Comment: @user3157061 Upvote the answer if this/any answer is/was helpful to you for the future readers.