# Passing command-line arguments to python unittests

Tags: python, unit-testing

Is there a way to do something like this in python?

```
$ python tests/tests.py verbose

# in the file
if __name__ == '__main__':
   unittest.main()
```

Basically I want to be able to parse extraneous sys args from the command line, but when I try, I get something like:

> AttributeError: module '**main**' has no attribute 'verbose'

Comment: What code gave that error?

Comment: @APhillips no, I mean when you use unittests it passed the sys.argv args to it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python, unit test - Pass command line arguments to setUp of unittest.TestCase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842168/python-unit-test-pass-command-line-arguments-to-setup-of-unittest-testcase)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply pass in `--verbose` from the command line, like this:

```
python tests/tests.py --verbose
```

When the unittest framework is called with `unittest.main()` is will still understand the same command line arguments as when the framework is called with `python -m unittest` as [documented here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#command-line-options). To enable verbosity, the option is the flag (prepended with two hyphens) [`--verbose`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#cmdoption-unittest-discover-v). There is no reason to make any changes to your code. The following is all you need:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
   unittest.main()
```

Of course, if you want to support options other than those provided by the framework, then you would need to handle those yourself.

Comment: thank you very much, this is by far the best answer (including all from the other question).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to process the sys args before those are passed to `unittest.main()`. For example:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if 'verbose' in sys.argv:
        sys.argv = sys.argv[:-1]  
    else:
        logging.disable(1e6) # suppress logging
    unittest.main()
```